# What is this ? Found under my bed

Tags: species-identification

[image][image]

Found under my bed. Looked and there was nothing else like it or eggs of any kind.

Comment: It was dead. Looked to be dead for a while but I’m not sure

Comment: Hi welcoem to Bio. SE. Please provide your location and the approximate size of the specimen. Additional clearer pictures would also be helpful for anyone trying to help you identify this organism. In general, we have a [list of expectations](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info) for [tag:species-identification] questions here that should be met to avoid having your question closed (and, more importantly, to help you get a correct answer!!). Please [edit] your post to add more of this information. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

At a glance it looks like a flattened perfectly ordinary dead [woodlouse](https://www.google.com/search?q=woodlouse&rlz=1C1NHXL_enGB711GB711&sxsrf=ACYBGNRCoKbZZ2X2xDDHY0DhVsiqct8TgQ:1568241226583&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiv8O3p6cnkAhX2TxUIHTHAA-8Q_AUIESgB&biw=1266&bih=609) to me.

[image]